# PHP mail with multiple recipients; maillog in /var/log shows message "To Many Recipients..."

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I have a section of PHP code that runs on my host that is a CentOS system as follows:

```
$emails = json_decode(file_get_contents("email_list.txt"), true);
$email_list = implode(', ', $emails);
$subject = "OCI - system heartbeat failure detected";
mail($email_list, $subject, $message);
```

$email_list appears correct it shows this in debug:
"paul.smith@ourcompany.com, don.smith@ourcompany.com, neal.smith@ourcompany.com, adam.smith@ourcompany.com"

the string above is correct - each email address separated by a comma & space... and I am only doing 4 email addresses just like above.

But in my centOS maillog - /var/log/maillog  -- I’m getting messages that say “To Many Recipients” see last part of maillog below - If necessary I can attach entire log file?

Problem is only the last email on the email address of $email_list string above is receiving the email? Why are the others not receiving the emails? This used to work with multiple emails just like it is now with email1, email2, email3, …

Below is a brief section of the log file showing the "To Many Recipients" message - note the names and domains have be changed to protect the innocent:

to=paul.smith@mycompany.com,don.smith@mycompany.com,adam.smith@mycompany.com,neal.smith@mycompany.com, ctladdr=webmaster@xxxxxxx.net (48/48), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=120317, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (u1ONF1DA006037 Message accepted for delivery) Feb 24 15:15:02 cloud sendmail[6039]: STARTTLS=client, relay=mycompany-com.mail.protection.outlook.com., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384, bits=256/256 Feb 24 15:15:02 cloud sendmail[6039]: u1ONF1DA006037: to=, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=esmtp, pri=210670, relay=mycompany-com.mai...ction.outlook.com. [207.46.163.215], dsn=4.5.3, stat=Deferred: 452 4.5.3 Too many recipients (AS780090) Feb 24 15:15:02 cloud sendmail[6039]: u1ONF1DA006037: to=, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=esmtp, pri=210670, relay=mycompany-com.mai...ction.outlook.com. [207.46.163.215], dsn=4.5.3, stat=Deferred: 452 4.5.3 Too many recipients (AS780090) Feb 24 15:15:02 cloud sendmail[6039]: u1ONF1DA006037: to=, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=esmtp, pri=210670, relay=mycompany-com.mai...ction.outlook.com. [207.46.163.215], dsn=4.5.3, stat=Deferred: 452 4.5.3 Too many recipients (AS780090) Feb 24 15:15:03 cloud sendmail[6039]: u1ONF1DA006037: to=, delay=00:00:02, xdelay=00:00:02, mailer=esmtp, pri=210670, relay=mycompany-com.mai...ction.outlook.com. [207.46.163.215], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (<201602242315.u1ONF1ah006036@cloud.cbsdds.net> [InternalId=46398531701026, Hostname=CY1PR0301MB1306.namprd03.prod.outlook.com] 9849 bytes in 0.840, 11.446 KB/sec

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14389789).

Comment: I think you missed removing domain name from all references...

Comment: @DaveChen - thanks I may have to do one mail per recipient in a for loop - but with only 4 emails seems strange that I can not do multiple recipients just like I am and like the PHP Mail documents?

Comment: @GustavoRubio - your right thanks - did I get them all now?

Comment: ask your host what the mail server limits are.

Comment: I dont understand the logs.  3 deferred then 1 sent?  How many emails did you get?

Comment: Just one email was actually received - the last email address of $email_list went through. What I have done for now is a foreach loop on the $emails array as suggest by the link that @DaveChen supplied above. That is working currently for all email addresses get sent. I have request support from my host provider also about the issue.